# Generate Rule using John the Ripper

Tags: password-cracking

I'm new in it, so can you help me to generate following rule.
It should match less then 6 lowercase, uppercase or digital character and than have word password.
For example

> applepassword
>   Homepassword
>   dog1password

I decided make it in three lines. So, for lower case I'm trying this

```
[List.Rules:Pass]
   /?l <6 password
```

But it is not working

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found answer

```
[List.Rules:Pass]
   /?l <6$p$a$s$s$w$o$r$d
```

Comment: Hi Maria. Welcome to Security SE. Can you explain why this rule works?

Comment: @Jedi I think it takes word from password list which length less then 6. Then appends word password to it.